# Jquery UI dialog being called before initializing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

EDIT 3:  As I mentioned below, I am trying to initialize the dialog in the header and then use it in any page anywhere in the body. It works OK if I initialize it JUST BEFORE I call it... but that means initializing it every time I call it. I want to initialize once & use many times.

On Sunny's request, the code / HTML sequence is as follows:

WORDPRESS HEADER.PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http<?php echo (is_ssl())? 's' : ''; ?>://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
... Wordpress / template stuff here...
    <script src="../sma-js/jquery-ui-1.10.3/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="../sma-js/d3.v3/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="../sma-js/d3.tip.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="../sma-js/sma.d3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="../sma-js/google-maps/js/handlebars-1.0.0.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="../sma-js/google-maps/js/jquery.storelocator.js"></script>  
    <script src="../sma-js/moment.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="../sma-js/jquery.validate.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>    
    <script src="../sma-js/sma.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(window).load(function() {
            jQuery(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery( "#dialog" ).dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            buttons: { Ok: function() { jQuery( this ).dialog( "close" );  } }, 
            show: { effect: "blind", duration: 1000 }, 
            hide: { effect: "explode", duration: 1000 }
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<?php
    $body_class = '';
    $wrapper_class = '';
    if(is_page_template('blank.php')):
    $body_class = 'body_blank';
    $wrapper_class = ' class="wrapper_blank"';
    endif; 
?>

<body <?php body_class(array($avada_color_scheme,$body_class)); ?>>
    <div class="loader"></div>
    <div id="dialog" title="ABC" ></div>
```

Then in the page's template (after the `<?php get_footer(); ?>` statement) I call the dialog as part of a form submission as follows:

WORDPRESS PAGE TEMPLATE - LOGIN.PHP

```
// validate signup form on keyup and submit
    jQuery("#forgot-pwd").validate({
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            email: "Please enter a valid email address",
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {

            jQuery(".loader").fadeIn("fast");

            var ResetPwd = generatePassword();
            var ResetSalt = generateSalt();

            jQuery.ajax({                                      
                url: "/sma-php/pwd.php?var=PWDRES&typ=r&ste=" + Base64.encode(jQuery('#user-email').val()) + "&rp=" + Base64.encode(ResetPwd) + "&rs=" + Base64.encode(hex_sha512(ResetSalt)),  //the script to call to get data          
                dataType: 'text',                                                                                                               //data format
                success: function(data) {                                                                                                       //on receive of reply
                    jQuery(".loader").fadeOut("fast");
                    jQuery( "#dialog" ).html( data ).dialog( "open" );
                },
                error: function(data) {                                                                                                         //on receive of reply
                    jQuery( "#dialog" ).html( "An error occurred while sending you a new password.<br/><br/>Please try again or contact ABC for help...").dialog( "open" );         
                }, 
                complete: function(data) {                                                                                                      //on receive of reply
                    jQuery(".loader").fadeOut("fast");
                } 
            });
        }
    });
```

---

EDIT 2: In short I am trying to initialize the dialog in the header and then use it in any page;'s body, anywhere. It works OK if I initialize it JUST BEFORE I call it... but that means initializing it every time you call it.

By the way, I call the dialog to open in JS as part of form submission in the page's BODY as follows: (data is the result of an AJAX call):

```
jQuery( "#dialog" ).html( data ).dialog( "open" );
```

---

EDIT: On Lal's suggestion I tried "document ready" in the header per below with same reult:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      modal: true,
      autoOpen: false,
      buttons: { Ok: function() { jQuery( this ).dialog( "close" );  } }, 
      show: { effect: "blind", duration: 1000 }, 
      hide: { effect: "explode", duration: 1000 }
   });
});
</script>
```

---

I am using JQuery UI dialog widget but I keep getting (on some, not all, function calls):

```
Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'
```

I have the initialization code in the page's head (which I understand executes first during load) as such:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( "#dialog" ).dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: { Ok: function() { jQuery( this ).dialog( "close" );  } }, 
    show: { effect: "blind", duration: 1000 }, 
    hide: { effect: "explode", duration: 1000 }
});
</script>
```

and the following DIV as first statement after BODY open tag:

I call the dialog somewhere in the middle of my page with JS as part of a form submission, for example, a password reset form.

Why is this happening? Where should I be placing the div / init JS for this widget so it works as desired? I have not found any info specific to this so your help is appreciated!

Comment: I think you need to use document.ready()

Comment: Hi Lal, thanks for the suggestion. I have tried this too with the same result... it seems to be just the sequence by which the code runs when the page loads...

Comment: The error itself is clear enough.  you're trying to call the dialog method of jQuery UI before it is completely loaded.  So first initialize the jQuery Ui then call it.

Comment: Great, so how come the initialization is not happening but page has completed loading? I call the dialog as part of a success message in a form submission and I get this error (which happens long after page was loaded). Why? I guess the question is where should it be initialized so it is available for use anywhere in the page? Thanks!

Comment: hi test if ur page loaded jQuery ui by typing this in your console: `jQuery.ui` if returned undefined then ur jq ui is not loaded

Comment: you have autoOpen:false, but error seems says that you call method 'open' before initialization of dialog widget, would be nice if you could post when you call 'open' as well as initialization of dialog widget you have already posted

Comment: Hi Homan, thanks. It is loading JQ UI as the dialog works on some pages and the JQ UI link is in the header of the site. Thanlks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Hi vitaliy thanks for the suggestion. The physical sequence on the page is: (1) in the page's HEAD I include JQ and JQ UI links, (2) last thing before </HEAD is the JS to initialize the dialog, (3) first DIV after <BODY is the dialog empty DIV, (4) further below in the page I have a form, and as part of submission I call the "open". Does this make sense or am I doing something wrong in the order / placement?

Comment: can you add HTML part in question?

Comment: Hi Sunny, I have above. If I place all code here it will be too long (it is a Wordpress site). I will summarize above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery( "#dialog" ).dialog({
       modal: true,
       autoOpen: false,
       buttons: [{ text:'OK',click: function() 
           {jQuery(this).dialog("close");}
          }], 
       show: { effect: "blind", duration: 1000 }, 
       hide: { effect: "explode", duration: 1000 }
    });

   $("#dialog").dialog("open"); // just to try, remove this
 });
</script>
```

sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sunnykumar08/7j3fA/

Comment: Hi Sunny, I placed it in the header just before </HEAD> but result is the same. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Hi Sunny, same result I am afraid. I assume I place the code in the HEAD right? Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: BTW if I place my or your init code JUST BEFORE I call the dialog, it works just fine! If I leave the init in the HEAD or even in the BODY just after the dialog DIV, it fails... as if it is not running the init on page load...

Comment: I believe you're not wrapping the code inside $(document).ready(). I've updated the answer.

Comment: OK Sunny, it works! Bloody CYBERDUCK had quietly died and my saves were not updating the server php file... can you believe it?? THANK YOU FOR ALL THE HELP!!!

Answer (score 0):

From your markup, I'm guessing jQuery is called after jQuery UI on some pages. Either put all the scripts after `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` or force it to load jQuery in `<?php wp_header(); ?>` and make sure the scripts are after it.

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>

<!-- insert scripts after this point -->
 <script src="../sma-js/jquery-ui-1.10.3/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="../sma-js/d3.v3/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="../sma-js/d3.tip.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="../sma-js/sma.d3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="../sma-js/google-maps/js/handlebars-1.0.0.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="../sma-js/google-maps/js/jquery.storelocator.js"></script>  
<script src="../sma-js/moment.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="../sma-js/jquery.validate.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>    
<script src="../sma-js/sma.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(window).load(function() {
        jQuery(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery( "#dialog" ).dialog({
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons: { Ok: function() { jQuery( this ).dialog( "close" );  } }, 
        show: { effect: "blind", duration: 1000 }, 
        hide: { effect: "explode", duration: 1000 }
    });
});
</script>
```

Ps.

In your markup you're missing a closing script tag before the end of `</head>`

Comment: Hi Akamaozu, this was a comedy of errors at my end thanks to CYBERDUCK dying quietly and files updating locally but not on the server... the closing script tag was my copy / paste mistake, but it is in the code. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: No big deal. I've had worse happen :)